# Headers added by ActionFilterAttribute will not appear in ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I want to be able to inject headers to WebApi controller method context using an `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class HeaderInjectionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Request.Headers.Add("test", "test");  
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

and using this in a controller

```
[HeaderInjectionFilter]
public class MotionTypeController : ApiController
{
    public bool Get()
    {
        // will return false
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("test");        
    }
}
```

As I stated out in the comment the header injected by the Filter will not be part of the `HttpContext.Current`. When I set a breakpoint on the last line of `OnActionExecuting` in the attribute I can see that it is containing the header value in the request headers.

If I change my controller to

```
public class MotionTypeController : ApiController
{
    public bool Get()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.Add("test", "test");
        // will return true
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("test");        
    }
}
```

everything will work so I guess the `actionContext` of the `OnActionExecuting` is not the same as the `HttpContext.Current` of the controller.

How can I inject headers for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As I stated out in the comment the header injected by the Filter will
>   not be part of the HttpContext.Current

That's because you added it to the `actionContext.Request.Headers` collection. So make sure you are looking in the same place where you added it:

```
[HeaderInjectionFilter]
public class MotionTypeController : ApiController
{
    public bool Get()
    {
        return this.Request.Headers.GetValues("test").Any();
    }
}
```

and just forget about `HttpContext.Current`. Think of it as something that doesn't exist. Everytime someone uses `HttpContext.Current` in an ASP.NET application a little kitten dies.

Comment: First: Thx!. There are a lot of samples out there (even from MS) showing access to HttpContext.Current. Can you provide a good link to a resource showing how I e.g. can prevent access to it when I try to read Headers in a second Filter?